# Rails > Devise Gem: Can't find source of Log Out link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm using Devise for the first time and having some trouble locating the source of the 'Log Out' link appearing in my app.

I am at the root url. Here is my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  root 'posts#index'

  resources :posts
end
```

My application.html.erb file is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MembersOnly</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
    <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my posts/index.html.erb:

```
<h2>Posts Index</h2>

<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <p><%= post.title %></p>
    <p><%= post.content %></p>
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <p><%= post.user.username %></p>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Yet at localhost:3000, there is a 'Log Out' link appearing above the `h2`.

I have generated the Devise views into my project, and done a project-wide search. Nothing.
Where is it coming from?

Comment: What did you search for exactly?  Did you search for an occurence of `destroy_user_session_path` ?

Comment: Rockwell, thanks for the effort. I'm going to chalk this one up to a brain malfunction on my part or maybe some changes not taking effect for some reason. Either way, it's now working as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

May have been a case of changes not taking effect or just a brain malfunction. App is now correctly reflecting that link is coming from a new file I generated.